# Select in callee hierarchy in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, hierarchy

I have a method and I have built its callee hierarchy. Then, I have found usages of a certain exception limiting the scope to the callee hierarchy and I get some results. Is it possible to show some of those results in the callee hierarchy? I would like to know where it is used and which the relationship among the usages is.

For example, I have a method called x throwing exception y. Then, I build the callee hierarchy of x. Then, I look for usages of y limited to that scope. Then, I find several usages of y but I don't know which one is first in the calling hierarchy. And I don't want to look for it manually.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing the point :). It is not a strack trace. It is the IntelliJ functionality to build the callee hierarchy of a method.

Comment: Have you tried Analyze | [Stacktrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyzing-external-stacktraces.html)?

Comment: But, the point is that I don't want to analyze a particular execution. I would like to use the function
(navigate | call hierarchy)